# what difference between the twilio number type Local,Mobile and Toll-Free.Thx~

Tags: twilio

I request the Twilio Server for a AvailablePhoneNumberList.But I get three different number type.Should I purchase for Local,Mobile,or Toll-Free number?

Comment: Which country are you talking about?

Comment: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135367-Phone-Number-types-Twilio-offers-and-how-they-work

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are actually 4 kinds of numbers. You can [read all about the different number types here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135367-Phone-Number-types-Twilio-offers-and-how-they-work). But here's a quick rundown of them:

### Local numbers

These are numbers that are mapped to a local region. Normally you would be able to tell where the number was from if you were from the country, for example, in the UK numbers starting (+44)020 are London numbers. In the US a number starting (+1)415 is in San Francisco. These are useful for local businesses as the number can match up to where the business is located.

### National numbers

These are similar to local numbers except the geographic area they are tied to is the entire country. They are more useful for national scale businesses that want to be easily reached from anywhere in the country.

### Mobile numbers

If you want to use SMS messaging and want users to understand that easily, then mobile numbers are normally the best approach. They tend to have a different number to local or national numbers (for example in the UK they start with 07) and that stands out to users.

### Toll free numbers

These numbers are national scale numbers and mean that the end user does not pay to make calls to them. They are useful for support or helpdesk lines where the business can take on the cost of the call for the user.

As I said, there is [more detail on the Twilio site](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135367-Phone-Number-types-Twilio-offers-and-how-they-work) but I hope this helped.